# EGL_emulation failed to establish connection to host - android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, genymotion

I am trying to run a simple OpenGL program in Android. I am running this in an Android 4.1 emulator. I switched on its GPU emulation and it worked fine yesterday. When I ran that today, initially it was hanging saying, `OpenGL taking time to render - Wait or Close dialog box`. After few runs again it was crashing saying

```
E/EGL_emulation(2637): Failed to establish connection with the host
```

followed by

```
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: eglChooseConfig failed EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.chooseEglConfig(HardwareRenderer.java:852)
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:804)
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:747)
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1505)
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
11-30 11:48:10.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
```

I guess the emulator is not able to take control of the GPU of the system, so how do I avoid this error? How do I rectify this problem?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Oh!.. a simple restart of the emulator solved the problem for me. :)

Comment: What the hell? Same problem and definitely didn't solve it for me.

Comment: I had this problem in the Genymotion emulator, running android 4.3.  I just closed and restarted the emulator, and it worked...

Comment: Restarting the Genymotion emulator solved it for me too.

Comment: Couple of times it happened to me as well and it didn't turn up good even after several times of restarts. I had to delete that particular emulator, recreate it afresh then bang-on...it worked :)

Comment: This isn't really a solution but I had a lot of problems testing my OpenGL apps on the emulator. Even ones worked fine when I ran them on the same physical device it was supposed to be emulating. I would recommend just getting a physical device to run OpenGL apps on.

Answer (score 63):

This happens to me when my computer came out standby. Restart your virtual device.

Comment: It happens every time after mac sleeping. Need to fix reason, not consequences. Any solution?

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I sent a mail to Genymobile with the link of this topic. I can't do anything more..

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same problem in my Genymotion emulator while running a webview based application,I have restarted the emulator and it worked fine

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question and also it's been mentioned in the comments.

Comment: For me, the exact solution crashed Genymotion on to different computers, so it came from the code, not from the simulator, even if restarting it can help.