# nothing is being displayed after opening the app

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-manifest

i am facing a problem while running the app

I have three activities, there are-- MainActivity.java , a splash activity, and another activity called AirportGuide.

now when i run the app on the emulator, the splash sound is playing, but the screen is blank. after three seconds of splash, a new screen opens which is also blank. the app was working fine before i added AirportGuide class

here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton flightInfoButton;
ImageButton airportGuideButton;
ImageButton visitorInfoButton;
ImageButton saaDcaButton;
ImageButton cargoButton;



@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    flightInfoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flightInfo);
     visitorInfoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.visitorInfo);
     saaDcaButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.saaDca);        
    cargoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cargo);
   airportGuideButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.airportGuide);

   airportGuideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V){

            Intent openAirportGuide = new Intent( MainActivity.this, AirportGuide.class);
           startActivity(openAirportGuide);

        }
      });
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

}
```

and this is the AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name="com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
       <activity
         android:name="com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport.AirportGuide"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport.AIRPORTGUIDE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the stack trace

```
02-13 13:01:50.808: E/eglCodecCommon(2345): writeFully: failed: Broken pipe
02-13 13:01:50.808: E/eglCodecCommon(2345): writeFully: failed: Broken pipe
02-13 13:01:50.808: W/libEGL(2345): eglInitialize(0x96a31040) failed (EGL_SUCCESS)
02-13 13:01:50.808: E/EGL_genymotion(2345): tid 2345: eglChooseConfig(576): error 0x3001     (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
02-13 13:01:50.808: D/AndroidRuntime(2345): Shutting down VM
02-13 13:01:50.808: W/dalvikvm(2345): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0xa4cfdb20)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345): Process: com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport,  PID: 2345
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: eglChooseConfig failed EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at     android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.chooseEglConfig(HardwareRenderer.java:1173)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at  android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.loadEglConfig(HardwareRenderer.java:1135)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:1117)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:1057)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)        
 02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-13 13:01:50.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2345):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the splash activity

```
package com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{
MediaPlayer splashSound;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle splashScreen) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(splashScreen);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    splashSound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    splashSound.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainActivity = new               Intent("com.shashank.sharjahinternationalairport.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    splashSound.release();
    finish();
}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting an Activity in onPostExecute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600279/starting-an-activity-in-onpostexecute)

Comment: splash Activity code... @shashank

Comment: i added the splash.java code..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Restart your emulator. Test this on a hardware device and it will probably work.

Comment: Thank you, saved me! I am using Android Studio and Genymotion emulator, and I have realized that it does not like it when you switch projects and use the same emulator. But by restarting the emulator, my new project hooks up to it better and runs fine. No more broken pipe error!