# Android emulator Hardware Renderer issue

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, android-emulator, android-hardware

I work for the complete day on the Eclipse and run the apps on Emulator. But Unexpectedly sometimes the emulator Hangs up and continuously showing the error message. The Logcat is showing problem in HardwareRenderer.java [image]

However, Restarting the emulator solves the Issue but it wastes time. So, is there a possible way to avoid or Recover this problem.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but you should check out [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: @TylerMacDonell There is the same problem using GenyMotion see comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640139/egl-emulation-failed-to-establish-connection-to-host-android

Answer (score 1):

hello maybe it doesn't exactly fits into your problem...  but instead of using emulator you can try using blue stacks its really fast and easy to run.... if you are using blue stacks as your emulator first start start the blue stacks and then start eclipse or whatever IDE you are using. In eclipse you can find the blue stacks emulator in devices tab ..Hope it will be useful for you.

http://infopulseukraine.com/eng/blog/Software-Development/Mobile/Bluestacks_Eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Use Genymotion, you will never experience any emulator issues. 
http://www.genymotion.com/

Very fast emulator, requires VM installation to work.

Comment: Peoples are facing this problem in genymotion also see comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640139/egl-emulation-failed-to-establish-connection-to-host-android

Answer (score 1):

try this...

1. Go to windows
2. Android Virtual Device Manager
3. Select your current Virtual Device
4. Edit
5. Disable **Use Host GPU**
6. Ok

   Because if we enable Use **Host GPU** option, it requires high capability of your           system's graphics card but mostly user does not have high quality graphics card, so it gives rendering problems. To increase the performance, enable the **snapshot** option.

Comment: I have 1 GB nvidia graphics card in my laptop & I want that emulator should launch app as soon as possible, so usually for that I use Host GPU with 768 MB of RAM & I think snapshot option usually launch emulator faster(but not app) !