# Android App not connecting to internet on emulator

Tags: android, network-connection

The app does not connect to the internet. I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in my manifest and I checked the other applications on the emulator for example youtube and google search works but the application isn't able to load the page. This is my main java file.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebview ;
        myWebview  = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webz);

        myWebview.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/");

    }

}
```

and this is my main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hoda.myapplication.MainActivity">



    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webz"></WebView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the error i get

```
[ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(289)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: restart the emulator as suggested here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640139/egl-emulation-failed-to-establish-connection-to-host-android)

Comment: I have  next error [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(467)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS .what is problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling javascript and override the webviewclient to avoid redirection:

```
        WebView myWebview ;
        myWebview  = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webz);
        myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebview.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/");
```

and update the constraints of your WebView:

```
   <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/webz"></WebView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the emulator's graphics I believe as trying @diegoveloper 's solution on the emulator still did not load the page but trying it on an actual android device was successful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054762/14488588)
2. Restart the emulator (as suggested in another post and in the comments of this post)
3. If that doesn't work, restart your device.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

android:name="com.(your browser activity)"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">