# Webview causing app to crash instantly on launch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I am trying to create a WebView app capable of behaving like the Facebook Messenger chat bubble that can overlay above other apps using the following github project:
https://github.com/siddharth2010/Bubbles

I downloaded the project and launched it, it works just fine with default parameters, but when clicking the "bubble" I want it to display a website instead of the placeholder image and text it currently has.

Here are the modifications I made:

sample_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.irunawiki.irunawiki;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.irunawiki.bubbles.FloatingBubblePermissions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().getDomStorageEnabled();
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        FloatingBubblePermissions.startPermissionRequest(this);
        View startBubble = findViewById(R.id.start_bubble);
        startBubble.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimpleService.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
added these:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Attempting to run this in either the VM or an actual device will result in an immediate crash.

Curiously, it launches just find when only
`WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);` is uncommented, but any of the getSettings, setWebViewClient, loadUrl will cause the app to crash instantly on launch.

What exactly is causing the crash? I'm fairly new to Android Development but after hours of looking up stackoverflow posts with similar issues I have not been able to get it working...

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have start_bubble view in your activity_main layout.

You should add button to your activity_main and after that u should change this line to this.

`View startBubble = findViewById(R.id.start_bubble);`

`Button startBubble = findViewById(R.id.start_bubble);`

Comment: Actually the activity_main remains identical as in the github repository, it contains a button with id "start_bubble". I tried changing the View startBubble to Button startBubble, the same crash still occurs, I was however told to use logcat to debug what exactly the cause is, and the following error appears to cause the crash: "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.irunawiki.irunawiki/com.irunawiki.irunawiki.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: That's crash is normal because you don't have webview in your activity_main layout. You trying to reach webview in your activity_main.

Comment: Yeah it turns out that was it, I am trying to find an ID that wasnt in the current layout, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was trying to select a webview in a layout that wasn't active which caused the crash, the fix was to simply select the layout with the webview in it

Answer (score 0):

This is also very useful for those to handle webview crash and recover from it.

Termination Handling API
The Termination Handling API handles cases where the renderer process for a WebView object goes away, either because the system kills the renderer to reclaim necessary memory or because the renderer process crashes. By using this API, you let your app continue executing, even though the renderer process goes away.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/managing-webview#termination-handle

```
public class MyRendererTrackingWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public boolean onRenderProcessGone(WebView view,
        RenderProcessGoneDetail detail) {
    if (!detail.didCrash()) {
        // Renderer is killed because the system ran out of memory. The app
        // can recover gracefully by creating a new WebView instance in the
        // foreground.
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "System killed the WebView rendering process " +
                "to reclaim memory. Recreating...");

        if (mWebView != null) {
            ViewGroup webViewContainer =
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_web_view_container);
            webViewContainer.removeView(mWebView);
            mWebView.destroy();
            mWebView = null;
        }

        // By this point, the instance variable "mWebView" is guaranteed to
        // be null, so it's safe to reinitialize it.

        return true; // The app continues executing.
    }

    // Renderer crashes because of an internal error, such as a memory
    // access violation.
    Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "The WebView rendering process crashed!");

    // In this example, the app itself crashes after detecting that the
    // renderer crashed. If you handle the crash more gracefully and let
    // your app continues executing, you must destroy the current WebView
    // instance, specify logic for how the app continues executing, and
    // return "true" instead.
    return false;
}
```

}

Destroying webview

```
 private void destroyWebview() {
    if (webView != null) {
        Utilities.logThis("MainActivity destroyWebview  DESTROY WebView ... ACTION");
        //ViewGroup webViewContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.webview_container);
        webviewContainer.removeView(webView);
        webView.stopLoading();  // Stop any ongoing loading in case of a crash
        webView.onPause();      // Pause JavaScript execution
        webView.clearHistory(); // Clear WebView history
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.removeAllViews(); // Remove all child views
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.destroy();  // Destroy the WebView
        webView = null; // Set the WebView reference to null
        webViewClient = null;
    }
}
```

Reconstruction it programmatically

```
 public void setupWebview() {  

    //webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // Create a new WebView instance
    webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    // Add the WebView to the container
    webviewContainer.addView(webView);


    Log.d("setupWebview", "Webview created " + webView);

    //Enabling hardware acceleration for WebView can improve performance but may also lead to crashes. You can disable it if it's causing issues:
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8); // 8MB
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        webView.getSettings().setSafeBrowsingEnabled(false);
    }

    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054518/android-app-not-connecting-to-internet-on-emulator

    webView.setRendererPriorityPolicy(WebView.RENDERER_PRIORITY_BOUND, true);
    //webViewClient = new MyRendererTrackingWebViewClient(this, webView);
    webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();

    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
   

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies( webView, false);
}
```