# .NET MAUI WebView Crashes for Android - killing application

Tags: c#, android, maui

Here the last thing from the ouput window. This problem occurs after running sometime. I don't have any idea how to prevent from this.

I use WebView in my ContentPage for .NET MAUI program, in windows it works fine, but Android has this issue.

```
[chromium] [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(156)] Renderer process (23633) crash detected (code -1).
[chromium] [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(112)] Render process (23633) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing application.
```

I should be able to handle this before happening, IDK how to control it, it's not an exception to catch.

Comment: Did you use any third party nuget package or sdk in your project? Or did you try to debug to check which line cause this error?

Comment: In addition, what verstion of the android api did you test on?

Comment: I am testing on the latest Firetv [link](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/device-specifications-fire-tv-streaming-media-player.html)

Comment: Now I got this error after running many hours

[0:] Navigating to Web Media #: https://fast.com/
[cr_ChildProcessConn] onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=24147 bindings:W  S
[chromium] [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(156)] Renderer process (24147) crash detected (code 7).
[chromium] [FATAL:crashpad_client_linux.cc(732)] Render process (24147)'s crash wasn't handled by all associated  webviews, triggering application crash.
[libc] Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 0 (SI_USER) in tid 23933 (board.infoboard), pid 23933 (board.infoboard)

Comment: Added bug report https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16677

Comment: I was showing web pages one by one - this was creating a back history and that was causing the OOM - out of memory, now I clean the history frequently, and this problem has gone for now. Via the code :    webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.removeAllViews(); // Remove all child views
            webView.clearHistory();

Answer (score 0):

I was showing web pages one by one - infinitely - this was creating a back history and that was causing the OOM - out of memory, now I clean the history frequently, and this problem has gone for now.

```
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.removeAllViews(); // Remove all child views
webView.clearHistory();
```

Another thing I am doing is following this, which is using Termination Handling API

The Termination Handling API handles cases where the renderer process for a WebView object goes away, either because the system kills the renderer to reclaim necessary memory or because the renderer process crashes. By using this API, you let your app continue executing, even though the renderer process goes away.

[Webview causing app to crash instantly on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68842258/webview-causing-app-to-crash-instantly-on-launch/77303151#77303151)